# How to debug PHP MVC site in NetBeans

Tags: php, debugging, model-view-controller, netbeans, prestashop

I need to debug MVC site (PrestaShop eshop solution) to find methods called on specific actions and tweak them. I tried to read the code, but I think that debugging is the only option.

I'm using Netbeans along with Apache. I've got set up a PHP project and enabled xdebug.

When I debug the project it starts at index.php. Pressing f5 will finish the debuggin no matter where I place the breakpoint. Pressing F7 seems to display everything that's being touched.

My question is: how do I debug the way I want? Meaning placing a breakpoint somewhere and waiting for it to be touched?

Comment: don't be lazy, read the code. print a stack trace. http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php

Comment: woops, wrong link: http://php.net/manual/en/exception.gettrace.php

Comment: not being lazy. I spent the whole day on it :(. I will definitely read it. thanks

Comment: Set a breakpoint by clicking on the line number in the margin. Otherwise your code will be executed from start to end and nothing will happen in debugger. / Step-debug through multiple standard requests to the application to get used to the execution flow of the application.

Comment: thanks a lot. I was doing exactly this. The issue was that the code didn't hit the part of the code where the breakpoint was placed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for a specific method and you know the method name, in NetBeans, do a single left click on your project folder, then ctrl-F to open the "find" thingy. Type in your missing method and NB will tell you which file it's in so you can alter it.